# Длинная арифметика, возведение в степень C++

Tags: c++, длинная-арифметика

Требуется возвести число a в степень n. a и n подаются на вход в типе string. На данный момент я сделал только умножение длинных чисел, а вот как сделать возведение в неприлично большую степень - не знаю. Все что есть на данный момент:

```
int main()
{
    string a,n;
    int *A, *B, *C, cc;
    // cin >> a;
    // cin >> n;
    a = "11111111111548484544876466666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666664548484";
    n = "11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111115";
    A = new int [a.size()];
   
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        A[i] = a[a.size() - i - 1] - '0';

    // Умножение числа string само на себя 
    length = a.size() * 2 - 1 ;
    l = length;
    C = new int[length];
    for (int ix = 0; ix < length; ix++)
    {
        C[ix] = 0;
    }

    for (int ix = 0; ix < a.size(); ix++)
    {
        for (int jx = 0; jx < a.size(); jx++)
        {
            C[ix + jx] += A[ix] * A[jx];
        }
    }

    for (int ix = 0; ix < length-1; ix++)
    {
        C[ix + 1] +=  C[ix] / 10;
        C[ix] %= 10;
    }

    while (C[length] == 0)
        length-- ;
    for(int i = length - 1; i >- 1; i--)
        cout << C[i];

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Умножение есть? ну так умножайте, разлагая степень. Для обычных чисел это примерно так (это скорее не код, а псевдокод :))

```
long pow(long x, long p)
{
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) return x;
    long r = 1;
    while(p)
    {
        if (p%2 == 1) r*= x;
        x *= x;
        p /= 2;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Т.е. по сути просто разбираем степень по битику.

Если степень - `2k+1` - то это все равно, что `x^2` в степень `k` и умножить на `x`. Если `2k` - то просто `x^2` в степень `k`. Так что если нечетное - результат (изначально 1) умножили на `x`, все, `x` больше не понадобится, только `x^2` - возводим в квадрат, степень делим пополам...

Скажем, `x` в 11

```
  p          x            r
 11          x            1
 10          x            x
  5          x^2          x
  4          x^2          x*x^2=x^3
  2          x^4          x^3
  1          x^8          x^3
  0          x^8          x^3*x^8 = x^11
```

Думаю, несмотря на мое косноязычие, разберетесь :)

Comment: У меня главный вопрос - как задать размерность массива C, в котором будет храниться искомое число? Размерность массива C определяется так: количество символов исходного числа * на степень. Т.к. при умножении одного числа на другое (кол-во знаков одинаково) - полученное число имеет в два раза больше символов.

Comment: Ну, прикиньте исходя из `lg x^N = N*lg x` - т.е. знаков потребуется, грубо говоря, в степень раз больше. Но если вы взялись всерьез писать длинную математику - то, поверьте, куда быстрее (но при этом просто) будет брать, скажем, массив `int` по 4 байта, и хранить в каждом значение не более 2 байт. Все умножения у вас будут помещаться (только переносы надо делать сразу), а делений на неудобное для машины число 10 не будет - будут только деления на степени 2. Да, будет сложный перевод в строку и из строки, но зато вся математика будет выполняться существенно быстрее...

Comment: Ну или хотя бы храните в `int` десятичные куски - но до 10000 - все ж меньше и памяти потребуется, и действий...

Comment: Про разложение степени я понял, примерно так и хотел делать. Но вот про размер массива так и не дошло, точнее про хранение элементов массива. Вот кусок, где задается размер для умножения двух чисел.: length = a.size() * 2 - 1 ;
    l=length;
    C=new int [length]; Можете помочь кодом в этом плане хотя бы? Я не понял просто.

Comment: @Harry я может не до конца понял ваш подход, но не будет ли риска переполнения `int` а если брать всего 2 байта для каждой цифры ? и какое основание берёте в этом случае, двоичное? Помоему, лучше взять за основание большое число - скажем 10^9 тогда одна цифра длинного будет 9 десятичных цифр представляя его как например, типом `long long` - массив станет в 9 раз меньше, что также в 9 раз ускорит все операции над длинным числом

Comment: @user6908356 размер результата для умножение двух длинных должен быть не больше чем `a.size() + b.size()` с чего вы решили взять именно `2*a.size()`  вы выравниваете числа чтоли ?

Comment: Ну возведение в степень - умножить число само на себя. Я взял исходную строку и умножил на количество перемножений.

Comment: а ещё бы я делал само умножения не так "в лоб", а через БПФ.

Comment: @user6908356 Грубо говоря, так у вас будет N умножений там, где достаточно их логарифма...

Comment: За сегодня я так и не сдвинулся с мертвой точки... Эх(

Comment: @ampawd Если int - 4 байта, то умножение двух 2-байтовых чисел не выйдет за пределы 4 байтов. Естественно, эти 2 байта и есть одна цифра в системе по основанию счисления 65536 :)